# Styling current navigation menu item in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, menu

I would like to style currently active submenu item in Django. I am wondering how should I do it?
I can think of 2 ways:

- Django Side: where I compare current address with link and then I add  inside Django template
- jQuery side: where Django template knows nothing about active menu item nad I do highlights using jQuery

I am more prone to do it jQuery way, but is my way of thinking good? Is this solution not recommended somehow?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@Liarez in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29487731/2024807) wrote:

> In this example I make difference for 3 urls, this can be messy if you have an URL that is like /posts/whatever/contacts because there is 2 places that will return True (2nd and 3rd li)

So here is the better option for handling this:

```
{% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="{% if url_name == 'home' %}active{% endif %}">Home</li>
        <li class="{% if url_name == 'blog' %}active{% endif %}">Posts</li>
        <li class="{% if url_name == 'contact' %}active{% endif %}">Contact</li>
    </ul>
{% endwith %}
```

Now we don't have problem with duplications in our url paths. That will work, assuming that you have wrote your url patterns with names like this:

```
url(r'^$', 'home_view', name=u'home'),
url(r'^posts/$', 'posts_view', name=u'blog'),
url(r'^contact/$', 'contact_view', name=u'contact'),
```

Answer (score 4):

To show active tabs in menus & submenus I use *request.path* in the Templates and one class called *active*.

When you do

```
{{request.path}}
```

in a template it returns the url where you are(something like `/posts/1234`). So in your HTML you can do something like:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="{% if request.path == '/' %}active{% endif %}">Home</li>
    <li class="{% if 'posts' in request.path %}active{% endif %}">Posts</li>
    <li class="{% if 'contact' in request.path %}active{% endif %}">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

In this example I make difference for 3 urls, this can be messy if you have an URL that is like **/posts/whatever/contacts** because there is 2 places that will return True (2nd and 3rd li)

But If you have very different urls this could be one of the easiest ways to do what you're trying to do